# facebook stream.publish

Tags: facebook

I'm making a facebook app and using [stream.publish](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish) to share something on a wall.

However for the 1) attachemnt link, and the 2) the FB UI action link, when I click either, it will load the page in the same browser window.

I would like to somehow add into these links something like target="_blank" so it opens the link in a new tab.
I know this is possible because when I share a video on youtube it has a target="_blank" on the action link and on the share link.

Does anyone know the trick?

I've tried code like this (I inserted the target blanks) but it doesn't add a target element in the hyperlinks:

```
 FB.ui(
   {
     method: 'stream.publish',
     message: 'Check out this great app! http://apps.facebook.com/{your_app}',
     attachment: 
     {
       name: 'Connect',
       caption: 'The Facebook Connect JavaScript SDK',
       description: (
         'A small JavaScript library that allows you to harness ' +
         'the power of Facebook, bringing the user\'s identity, ' +
         'social graph and distribution power to your site.'),
         'media': [{ 
            'type': 'image', 
     'target': '_blank', 
            'src': 'http://test3.com/test.png', 
            'href': 'http://test3.com'}],



       href: 'http://test2.com',
       target: '_blank'

     },

     action_links: [
       { text: 'Code', href: 'http://github.com/facebook/connect-js' }
     ],
     user_message_prompt: 'Share your thoughts about Connect',
     target: '_blank'
   }

  );
```

Does anyone have any idea how youtube can accomplish the targets

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is

display: 'popup', after method: 'stream.publish'

target is in reference to a fb user_id to post a wall-to-wall